# JButton how to set roll over icon bounding

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

So I've got code that will set a JButton equal to an ImageIcon. As well, when I hover over the image it will display a new ImageIcon, but the way I have it is that the new IconImage is actually a bit larger than the original. Now the problem is that it still exists within the bounds of the button, so say my button size is 100, 250 and the roll over IconImage is 120, 270 well then the issue is that 20 pixels from each side is cut off.

My solution thus far is actually making the button equal to the size of the roll over IconImage, but my issue with that is that even if I mouse over, up to 20 pixels, beside the image the rollOver effect still happens. Now that's obviously because I changed the bounds of my JButton.

If anyone has any solutions they can think of, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
singlePlayerButton = new ImageIcon("GUIImages\\singlePlayerButton.png");
rollOverSinglePlayerButton = new ImageIcon("GUIImages\\rollOverSinlgePlayerButton.png");
btnSinglePlayer = new JButton(singlePlayerButton);
btnSinglePlayer.setOpaque(false);
btnSinglePlayer.setContentAreaFilled(false);
btnSinglePlayer.setBorderPainted(false);
btnSinglePlayer.setFocusPainted(false);
btnSinglePlayer.setBounds(320, 25, 275, 130);
btnSinglePlayer.setRolloverIcon(rollOverSinglePlayerButton);
mainMenu.add(btnSinglePlayer);
```

Imagine that I've declared the variables I'm using else where.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply make sure both icons have exactly the same size. Add a transparent border to the smaller one if necessary.

This will make everything easier.

Comment: It would I agree, but then there's not enough animation to let the user know that it's a button. I do want the button to get bigger, if there is no known method I will keep it as is. It does work, just that little tid-bit that is bugging me.

Comment: If you didn't remove the border of the button, it would be obvious that it is a button. If you don't like the standard borders, you could add borders to your icons directly to make it clear that they represent a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "MouseListener" instance to your button and implement the "mouseEntered" method. Then you can change your button (bouds, imange, ...) and redraw it on the screen if neccessary. See the javadoc of JButton and MouseAdapter class for furter information.

Comment: It is not a mouse entered that I am looking for. I'm looking for hovering, I can't redraw the button every time it is hovered, because then I would have to make sure it is AGAIN redrawn when there is no mouse hovering over it.